# WebStorm after reformat code - what is this?

Tags: performance, webstorm, reformat

This is my HTML structure:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">Superga</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Balance</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Birkenstock</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Havaianas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Punto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marjin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I use WebStorm's reformat code (<kbd>Alt + Command + L</kbd>), it changes to:

```
<ul class = "list-unstyled" >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Superga</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Nike</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >New Balance</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Birkenstock</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Havaianas</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Punto</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Marjin</a ></li >
      <li ><a href = "#" >Puma</a ></li >
</ul >
```

Why does it do this. Why is there blank space between the attribute string and the tags?

Comment: **1)** *"Why divs has a blank?"* Which `divs`? I see no `div` tags here at all. **2)** Show your settings for that language. **3)** In any case: please try Default code style. **4)** Yes -- there are option for HTML that will insert spaces around `=` and space after tag name (as in `</li >`) -- just turn them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML, Other, Spaces, `"Around "=" in attribute"` and `"After tag name"`

See the comment above